# Let f be a twice differentiable function. The conditions are: $f(a)=f(b)=0$,$f(x)>0 \forall x \in (a,b)$, prove that f''(c)<0 , for some $c \in (a,b)$

Tags: calculus

I haven't been able to relate the the fact that f'(x) would have a root in (a,b).
My idea was to use LMVT on f'(x), but I'm unable to connect it to the aforementioned idea, and also that f(x)>0.

Comment: Hint: apply Mean Value Theorem to $f'(x)$.

Comment: I'm sure this is probably a duplicate, so not answering.  But... for an outline, first there exists $d \in (a, \frac{a+b}{2})$ with $f'(d) > 0$ and there exists $e \in (\frac{a+b}{2}, b)$ with $f'(e) < 0$.  Then, there exists $c \in (d, e)$ with $f''(c) < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)f'(x)$

So,$g(a)=g(b)=0$

By Rolle's theorem we must have $g'(c)=0$ for at least one $c\in(a,b)$

$\Rightarrow(f'(c))^2+f(c)f''(c)=0$

$$\Rightarrow f''(c)=-\frac{(f'(c))^2}{f(c)}<0$$ since $f(c)>0$

and we are done

Comment: your choice of function was very nice, thank you. I understood your solution :)

Comment: @q123LsaB : Check the page https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171392/maverick for similar questions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch: Apply MVT to $f$ to find two points $x < y$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(x) > 0$ and $f'(y) < 0$. Next apply MVT again but this time to $f'$ on the interval $(x,y)$. This will give you a point $c\in (x,y) \subseteq (a,b)$ for which $f''(c) < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any $a'\in (a,b).$ Since $f(x) > 0$ for all $x\in (a,b),\ $ it follows that $\ b<a',\ $ and the result follows immediately from applying MVT to $(a',b).$

Note that we don't need to use the fact that $f$ is twice-differentiable, which means the result is true even if $f$ being twice-differentiable was not a condition.